# Is there a safe way to get 12 V power from an ATX power supply when the computer is turned off?

Tags: atx

I have some LED stripes to illuminate my workspace. Since I have nothing else at hand, I connected it to the 12V rail of my PSU in my computer. This works very well when the computer is turned on, but I would like to be able to use the lights also when the computer is not running.

Comment: Why not just acquire a separate power supply?

Comment: There is *powered off*, and there is *disconnected*. Assuming your ATX PS still connected to mains *and* computer, there's 5 V stand by - typically no more than 10 W, with the computer consuming an unknown amount. Assuming your workspace to feature a monitor, it may be more useful to use that for illumination. And even a small EE challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would mean the power supply is turned on, because you don't have 12V at standby.
But if your LED lights don't take more than 5 to 10W, you could use the 5V standby output by using a boost converter from 5V to 9-12V.
Your power supply should be capable of providing more power (in watts) than what your LED light needs.

Another way of doing this WITHOUT a boost converter is to rewire or re-arrange the LEDs on your strip so that they're in parallel instead of being in series (typically there are 3 LEDs in series with 1 or 2 resistors on 12V strips), so that the strip can run at 3-5V, though this would be less efficient, but would get the job done.

If you don't know the details or need more info on how to do that, let me know in the comments below this answer, and I will add the necessary details here.